# Potnetial Resource Leak with IOUtils Persists like a Stubborn Mule

Tags: java, eclipse, memory-leaks, io

I'm using `IOUtils` to parse `JSON` from a `HttpServletRequest request`:

```
baseRequest.setAuthentication(null);
    
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
baseRequest.setHandled(true);   
    
PrintWriter writerResponse = response.getWriter();
    
    
-> String data = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"); <-
```

But Eclipse complains of a potential resource leak:

```
Potential resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' may not be closed
```

Even when I surround it with a `try/finally` block and close via `IOUtils.closeQuietly()` the error persists like a stubborn mule.

```
String data = "";
try {
    data = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
} catch (IOException e) {
       
} finally {
       IOUtils.closeQuietly(request.getInputStream());
}
```

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

P.S

While the code below:

```
try {
    String data = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
} catch (IOException e) {
       
} finally {
       IOUtils.closeQuietly(request.getInputStream());
}
```

does not throw any error, as soon as I try using the value 'data' anywhere in my code (even in the try statement) the error shows up again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is correct.  `getInputStream` may well return a *new* input stream each time you call `getInputStream`, so closing a new input stream doesn't help.

Save the input stream in a variable.  Best of all, use try-with-resources:

```
try (InputStream stream = request.getInputStream()) {
  data = IOUtils.toString(stream, "UTF-8");
}
```